# Can IOS Native UI be used in a game

Tags: ios

Developing on a Mac with Apple development toolkits can I combine native iOS UI with game graphics?

I've not yet seen an example of this and all my searches have been drowned out by crossplatform UI technologies.

---

Edit

UIKit and SpriteKit are somewhat combinable apple modules.

I get the impression that you might be able to present a scene in a UIKit based project, please correct me if you know better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the links below could be helpful to you if you are talking about embedding an SKView into a UIViewController:

- This is a very well done [How To](https://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2016/11/how-to-embed-spritekit-in.html) that will help you in setting up a `UIView` as a `SKView` into any `UIViewController`.
- You can always refer to the [Apple Documentation on SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/spritekit/) for exhaustive information.

If you are referring instead of using graphical UIKit elements (such as switches, sliders, tableviews, etc.) then you should use UIView animations:

- this [WWDC2016 Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/216/) can be helpful;
- refer to [UIView animations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration);

a simple animation could be achieded as such (use :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
   self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width / 2, height: self.frame.size.height / 2)
}, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
    // do whatever you want when the animation has completed.
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, there are many possible answers I think to this questions but in summary I think it is "yes".

Comment: I found UIKit and Core Graphics to be what I am looking for, although not primarily inteded for games, my game is a special case. Note to readers, take care about the move from opengl ES etc to metal and Quartz when it comes to mixing native constrols and graphics.